# Selenium find the search bar and search things

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

[image: This is the search bar that i want to find using the webdriver]

```
!pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
search = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"gLFyf")
search.send_keys("test")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The above is my code, when it run to

```
search = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"gLFyf"), there is an errror "name 'By' is not defined.
```

I make references from https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/ , but its not working, What can i do?

I expected that I can search the word "test" in the google website search bar by using selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```